# How to display the overclocked (actual) CPU frequency in C#

Tags: c#, cpu

I want to do the get the actual frequency of the processor, but when I try to take it from `WMI` and `Win32 Processoralways` returns to the default clock, even if I take the `MaxClockSpeed`.

Actually I have this code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mosProcessor = 
          new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

foreach (ManagementObject moProcessor in mosProcessor.Get())
{
     cpuclock_label.Text = moProcessor["MaxClockSpeed"].ToString() + " Mhz"
}
```

But it returns the default maximum clock and not the overclocked frequency.

I even tried to get the frequency in the System Register from

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/System/CentralProcessor/0

but even this returns the default frequency... any idea???

Comment: Do you mean CPU's current frequency?

Comment: @AleksandarToplek no, the current frequency display the same frequency of the MaxClockSpeed